# Python: unsupported operand 'str' and 'float' in simple calculation of floats

Tags: python, string

What seems to be the issue here?

```
THREAD = 2.55

bags_value = input('Bags value in gold: ')
cloth_price = input('Cloth price in gold: ')
dust_price = input('Dust price in gold: ')

bags_cost = (2 * THREAD) + 6 * ((2 * dust_price) + 2 * (5 * cloth_price))

profit = bags_value - bags_cost
print(profit)
```

PyCharm shouts with:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Same happens if I execute the script from the terminal.

However it works perfectly under ipython. wtf

Comment: `input()` returns strings. convert them to float

Comment: Why is he being down-voted? He provided all the relevant code and the error message. It was a simple fix, but I thought this is precisely what SO was for.

Comment: If it runs with ipython then ipython is running with Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` returns `string`. You have to cast to `float`:

```
THREAD = 2.55

bags_value = input('Bags value in gold: ')
cloth_price = input('Cloth price in gold: ')
dust_price = input('Dust price in gold: ')

bags_cost = (2 * THREAD) + 6 * ((2 * float(dust_price)) + 2 * (5 * float(cloth_price)))

profit = bags_value - bags_cost
print(profit)
```